# Issues with Unintended Animation Impact on CSS Elements - Enlarging the Button Causes Changes in Other Elements

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that when hovering over a button element, where I increase the padding by 15px, it enlarges the element with the 'contact' class, causing the footer to fluctuate during the animation. I would like only the button to enlarge during the execution, without affecting any other elements. I already have 'box-sizing: border-box' set globally.

```css
:root {
    /* rgba(116, 116, 116) */
    --gray-color: #ededed;

    /*  --background-color: #fff; */
    --background-color: #1b1a1a;

    /*  --font-color: #000; */
    --font-color: #cecece;

    /* FOOTER COLOR */
    --footer-color: #2c2b2b;

    --nav-color: #747474;

}

.contact {
    width: 100%;
}

.contact-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    position: relative;
    width: 78%;
    left: 11%;
}

form,
.profiles {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 49%;
}

form {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

label {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: var(--font-color);
    transition: 0.3s;

}

form input,
textarea {
    margin: 10px 0 25px 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid var(--font-color);
    color: var(--font-color);
    transition: 0.3s;

}

textarea {
    resize: none;
    width: 100%;
}

button {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: var(--background-color);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    border: 1px solid var(--font-color);
    color: var(--font-color);
    transition: 0.3s;
    cursor: pointer
}

button::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--footer-color);
    transform-origin: right;
    transform: scaleX(0);
}

@keyframes animationFormBtnAfter {
    0% {
        transform: scaleX(0);
        transform-origin: left;
    }

    50% {
        transform: scaleX(1);
        transform-origin: left;
    }

    51% {
        transform-origin: right;

    }

    80% {
        transform: scaleX(0);
    }
}

button span {
    display: block;
}

button:hover::after {
    animation: animationFormBtnAfter 0.8s;
}

.contact button:hover+.profiles {
    transform: translateY(0);
    /* Reset transform for other elements */
}

.contact button:hover+.profiles+#emailForm {
    transform: translateY(0);
    /* Reset transform for other elements */
}


button:hover {
    padding: 15px;
    width: 120px;
}

.email-contact {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 50%;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: var(--font-color);
    transition: 0.3s;

}

.social-media-contact,
.email-contact {
    background-color: var(--background-color);
    transition: 0.3s;

}

.email-contact span {
    font-weight: 500;
}

.social-media-contact {
    font-size: 3rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.social-media-contact a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(120, 119, 119);
    padding: 0px 15px;
    transition: .4s;
}
```

```html
 <div class="contact">
            <h1 class="title">Contact</h1>

            <div class="contact-container">
                <form id="emailForm">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">

                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">

                    <label for="textarea">Message</label>
                    <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"
                        placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>

                    <button type="button" onclick="sendEmail()" name="submit">Send</button>
                    <div id="response"></div>

                </form>
                <div class="profiles">
                    <div class="email-contact"><span>Email</span>jarekbabiak3@gmail.com</div>
                    <div class="social-media-contact">
                        <a href="https://github.com/Masohas1" target="_blank"> <i
                                class="fab fa-brands fa-github"></i></a>
                        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jarek-babiak/" target="_blank"> <i
                                class="fab fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/jarek.babiak.2" target="_blank"> <i
                                class="fab fa-brands fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href="CV.pdf" download title="Pobierz CV"> <i class="fas fa-solid fa-file"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You have set the height of the email block to 50% so when you add extra height to the whole - which you do when the button is hovered - the height of the email block increases.